# VCL Showing a different form

Tags: c++, forms, vcl

I am creating a VCL forms application with multiple forms. I have created a new form called formCreateAppointment.

I am trying to load the form via this code in a menuItem:

```
formCreateAppointment.Show();
```

I am getting this error:

E2451 Undefined symbol 'formCreateAppointment'

Do I have to declare this form as a 'global' object or something similiar?

Thanks

**More Info**

The form 'formCreateAppointment' is under the Project->Options->Auto-create forms. When I use the code:

```
formCreateAppointment->Show();
```

My code will not compile and I get the following error:

E2451 Undefined symbol 'formCreateAppointment'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a new Form class in the IDE, the generated .hpp file contains a global pointer for you, eg:

```
#ifndef Unit2H
#define Unit2H

#include <Classes.hpp>
//...

class TformCreateAppointment : public TForm
{
    //...
}; 

extern PACKAGE TformCreateAppointment *formCreateAppointment; // <-- here

#endif
```

It sounds like you have not `#include`'d that .hpp file into your main code, eg:

```
#include "Unit2.hpp" // (or whatever you decided to name that Form's unit as)
```

If you set that Form to be Auto-Created in the Project Options, that global pointer will be automatically instantiated at program startup for you (by inserting a call to `Application->CreateForm()` in your project's `WinMain()` function).  Otherwise, you have to instantiate it manually in your code using the `new` operator instead.

Either way, the variable is a pointer.  VCL objects cannot be instantiated on the stack, only the heap.  You have to use the `->` operator to access members of the Form object, eg:

```
formCreateAppointment->Show();
```

If you want to use the `.` operator instead then you have to dereference the pointer first:

```
(*formCreateAppointment).Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have created the form as a local variable somewhere else, that's why you don't have access to it from where you are trying to call it.

You can use three approaches to solve this:

- Create the form in the exact place where you are going to show it. However, that only works if you are going to call the form from one place
- Create it as a global variable.
- Create it in the heap, and store a pointer to it in your main form. For example:

  ```
  class MyMainForm
  {
  public:
      MyMainForm()
      {
          //create the form in the constructor
          formCreateAppointment = new myOtherForm();
      }
      ~MyMainForm()
      {
          delete formCreateAppointment;
      }
      //code
  private:
      myOtherForm * formCreateAppointment;
  }
  ```

Comment: The form is not a variable. It is a form that has controls and other objects associated with it. Its name is formCreateAppointment. Do I not just use a simple .show method to display it?

Comment: @user, the form is not a variable, it's an _object_. Just like any other object, it should first be created, and only after that you can call it's methods.